# Why am I getting a message to "Specify the table containing the records you want to delete"

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

In access I am trying in a delete query to delete rows from `tblA` that have same data in `tblB`
I tried the following but it is telling me to "**Specify the table containing the records you want to delete**"

```
DELETE 
[tblA].fldA, 
[tblA].fldB, 
[tblA].fldC,
[tblA].fldD
FROM 
tblA 
LEFT JOIN 
tblB 
ON 
[tblA].fldA = tblB.ID
WHERE 
(([tblB].[ID]=[tblA].[fldA]) 
AND 
([tblB].[fldB]=[tblA].[fldB]) 
AND
([tblB].[fldC]=[tblA].[fldC]) 
AND
([tblB].[fldD]=[tblA].[fldD]));
```

I can't see what what I am missing here.
I also tried the following but results in the same message

```
DELETE 
[tblA]
FROM 
[tblA]
LEFT JOIN 
[tblB]
ON 
[tblA].fldA = tblB.ID
WHERE 
(([tblB].[ID]=[tblA].[fldA]) 
AND 
([tblB].[fldB]=[tblA].[fldB]) 
AND
([tblB].[fldC]=[tblA].[fldC]) 
AND
([tblB].[fldD]=[tblA].[fldD]));
```

Comment: The syntax is `DELETE tablealias1 FROM tablealias1 LEFT JOIN tablealias2 ON ... WHERE ...` and not `DELETE tablealias1.columnname1, tablealias1.columnname2, tablealias1.columnname3 FROM tablealias1 LEFT JOIN tablealias2 ON ... WHERE ...`

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but I am getting the same message

Comment: Oh sorry, missed the `ms-access` tag.  You could try `DELETE tbla.* FROM tbla left join tblb on ... `

Comment: The link you provided gave me the answer. Thanks derpirscher

Answer (score 0):

This solved it

```
DELETE 
FROM [tblA] AS T
WHERE Exists (SELECT * FROM tblB WHERE 
([tblB].[fldA]=T.[fldA]) 
AND 
([tblB].[fldB]=T.[fldB]) 
AND
([tblB].[fldC]=T.[fldC]) 
)
```